# How to grant a normal user limited privileges to specific directory and run files without sudo

Tags: linux, permissions, python, sudo

Sorry for my expressions, and I hope I've described my question as clearly as possible.

Using Red-hat system. Currently I own a superuser in the system, and I have to do`sudo python cuckoo.py` in order to run this python program, and it reads & writes in a specific directory, called "cuckoo".

Now I want to give a normal user access to this "cuckoo.py", as well as the working directory. However meanwhile I also don't want to grant this user superuser privilege because they may damage my system.

So how can I let the normal user just directly call `python cuckoo.py`and won't receive any error saying "Permission Denied"?

Any help and comments are appreciated. And if I have some really bad word phrases to make it unclear, please point it out as well and I will do my best to explain in more details.

Thanks!

EDIT: Maybe my words are not quite clear... I don't want to include this normal user in "root". Currently I've created a group and have added this normal user into the group, and the directory permission is set to be 755. But I want the group to have the permission to write in order to run `cuckoo.py` smoothly. So I wonder how to make both root and this group have permission for read, write & execute?

Comment: Does the `cuckoo.py` script really need to be run as root have read/write access to the directory?

Comment: @JuliePelletier I added the normal user to the group and the group has the permission to execute, then he can do "python cuckoo.py" without calling sudo. But because the group can't write, so this program won't be run successfully. Not sure if this answers your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only reason the script needs to be run as root is to read/write to your specific directory, there are two ways for you to solve this (to allow a regular user to run the script successfully):

1. Created a group, make the folder you are working in owned by that group, and add the user to that group.

```
sudo groupadd <groupname>
sudo usermod -a -G <groupname> <username>
sudo chgrp -R <groupname> <folder>
```

2. Simply change the world permission of the folder (not recommended if you don't want any user on your computer to be able to access your `cuckoo` folder).

```
sudo chmod -R 664 ./cuckoo
```

*This permission allows read and write for owner, group and world*

Comment: Those options don't run the script as root.

Comment: What do you mean? The script won't need to be run as root, because these commands allow the script to write to the working folder as a normal user.

Comment: I really don't know about whether it does or doesn't need to run as `u`, so I'll abstain from voting for now, but it may be good to tag @JuliePelletier to let him know you answered his comment, and see what he has to say.

Comment: Standard Linux stuff - you created a group with access to the folder, added your regular user to that group, now the user has permissions to that folder.

Alternatively you can chown the folder to that particular user, if you only want one user to have access to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I may have misinterpreted the question. If the script needs to be run as root regardless, and you want a regular user to be able to execute it, you can use follow the instructions found over on [this AskUbuntu question.](https://askubuntu.com/a/167885/237790)

> Keep in mind that you will need to have the permissions locked down tight in this file for this to be secure.
>
> Make the file owned by root and group root:
>
> `sudo chown root.root <my script>`
>
> Now set the sticky but, make it executable for all and writable only by root:
>
> `sudo chmod 4755 <my script>`
>
> Keep in mind if this script will allow any input or editing of files, this will also be done as root.
>
> The SetUID bit makes a script or binary always run as the owner of the file/binary, an example of such a binary is 'passwd'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think my issue is more like give a normal user restrict root access to execute python and read & write a directory. But otherwise I don't want that normal user to have any other root access, and these files should also be accessible to other superusers.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't want to include this user as root, so now I've added this normal user to a group as you've suggested above. And the group right now has the permission to read and execute, but can't write, which would cause trouble to run "cuckoo.py" successfully. Any way to fix this permission?

Comment: @Xiechen As I said in my answer above, you need to `chmod` with permissions 664 for owner and group read+write.

Comment: @joejoe31b:  Apparently I was the one who misunderstood.  Note that this answer is flawed though.  The sticky bit only works with binary executables so you should remove this answer altogether.